# Confusion on AC in LIVE & NEUTRAL WIRE

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, electronics

So if an AC current means the elctrons are alternating or changing direction in a given time, how does this apply to live & neutral wire, don't they flow in one direction only? Please answer it as simple as possible, I'm only a high school kid.

Comment: Wires allow current flow in both directions.

Comment: There is an AC voltage between the *live* wire and ground while there should *not* be a significant AC voltage between the *neutral* wire and ground.  I'm not clear on why this might be interpreted to mean the electrons flow in one direction only in these wires.  Would you please edit your question to explain your reasoning?  Also, see this related Q & A here:  [Difference between live and neutral wires](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/209052/140996)

Comment: The answer that Hal Hollis linked is pretty long. The short version is, the entire power grid is connected to Earth at regular intervals because otherwise, atmospheric electricity could charge the overhead wires to dangerously high voltage with respect to Earth. The "neutral" wire is whichever one is connected to Earth. All of the other wires are "Live." If _you_ are connected to Earth, and you touch the neutral, you won't get hurt, but if you touch a "live" wire, then it will hurt.

Comment: Crossposted to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/401559/52589

Comment: @SolomonSlow but the hot wire is connected to the neutral wire in a circuit. The current flows in a closed circuit. And that's even before we consider real flow vs conventional. Totally confused.  In an ac circuit isn't current alternating? Why should the hot wire be any more dangerous than the neutral? I'm caught up on definitions here. Please help 

Comment: @HörmannHH, the neutral wire for residential power in the US is connected to the earth ground near the residence. Copper pipe for water plumbing is also connected to earth ground. If you touch with one hand the copper piper and, with the other hand, the neutral wire, you won't be electrocuted since both are connected to the 0V reference, the earth ground. However, if instead of the neutral, you touch the live wire, you will be electrocuted since the live wire voltage, relative to ground, is 120 VAC (in the US).

Comment: @HörmannHH, Re, "the hot wire is connected to the neutral wire in a circuit." Not _directly_ connected.  If you try to make a direct connection between them, the outcome will be a loud pop, a bright flash, a shower of burning metal sparks, and then you will be laying on your back in the attic crawl space in complete darkness. (Don't ask me how I know!) I think what you're trying to describe is how the hot wire and the neutral wire both carry the current that powers some appliance. But, as Alfred Centauri says, _neutral_ is special because the voltage between neutral and Earth is close to 0.

Answer (score 4):

This is a follow-up to a comment I left at the OP's closed question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/435097/9887)

> how does this apply to live & neutral wire, don't they flow in one
>   direction only

Here's an image of 240VAC versus 240VDC

[image]

Stipulate that the live wire has 240VAC relative to the neutral (return) wire and that the neutral wire is held at 0V.

This means that the live wire is *alternately* more positive and then more negative with respect to the neutral wire.

Assuming a resistive load (imagine a light bulb connected between live and neutral), the mobile electrons in the bulb filament move away from the neutral towards the live wire when the live wire voltage is positive and move from the live wire towards the neutral when the live wire is negative.

Thus, the current through the bulb (and wires) *alternates* in direction as the live voltage alternates in polarity.  That is, the current is an alternating current (AC) and not a DC (unidirectional) current.

Comment: But how does the neutral wire is 0V all the time, doesn't it alternates everytime?

Comment: @PCMining, what is the *it* that you think should be alternating?  Note *carefully* that I specified in the very first sentence that the live wire has 240VAC *relative* to the neutral wire.  Thus, the *voltage across* the live and neutral wires is alternating.  If a resistor is placed across the live and neutral wires, the voltage across the resistor is *alternating* and thus, the current through the resistor is *alternating*.  It's completely *irrelevant* to this result if the neutral wire is at 0V *with respect to ground*.

Comment: But the wire isn't. You are applying 240v ac to the wire. That's the ops, and mine, issue. There is a negative voltage at the neutral wire during half a full ac cycle .. Alternating current.

Comment: @HörmannHH, it simply *isn't* the case that "There is a negative voltage at the neutral wire during half a full ac cycle". Please take a look at this Wikipedia article [Split-phase electric power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-phase_electric_power) and see that the neutral wire is *grounded*, i.e., the voltage on the neutral wire is (ideally) the same as the ground, the 0V  reference voltage. The live wire(s) are alternately positive and negative with respect to the 0V neutral wire.

Comment: Net zero charge does not mean at all points in the wire  the potential is zero.

Answer (score 1):

As you have noted, there is a live and a neutral wire leaving the circuit breaker panel (*note 1) to your load.  Because this is alternating current, during half of the cycle the circuit in the live wire is flowing *out* of the panel, and during the other half it flows *in* to the panel.

Now, the key here is that during the time that current flows *out* the live wire, it flows back *in* the neutral wire.  The neutral wire completes the circuit, giving a return path for the current.  Similarly, when the current flows *in* the live wire, it flows *out* the neutral.  At any given time, whatever current flows through the live wire, an equal amount (*note 2) flows in the opposite direction through the neutral wire.  It's a great example of Kirchoff's current rule!

---

(*note 1)  Older panels use fuses instead of circuit breakers.  In either case, at the panel the neutral is connected to Earth ground.  But none of this matters for explaining your question.

(*note 2)  When things are working correctly, the currents should be equal and opposite.  Occasionally, the current finds another path back -- often through a human being, causing an electric shock.  We call this a "ground fault".  There are devices called "ground fault circuit interrupters" that measure the difference between the live and neutral currents; if the difference in current is large enough, they shut off the circuit.  You can often see these devices in bathrooms and kitchens, with buttons labelled "TEST" and "RESET".  Now you know what those are for!

Comment: But in an AC circuit, why would the current be 'returning' in either wire? doesn't the current occilate?

Comment: @DBWeinstein: Because Kirchoff's laws only care about what is happening at *one point in time*.  Whatever may have happened in the past or in the future completely does not matter.  So if current is flowing in the live wire *now*, it must return in the neutral  wire *now*; it does not matter that the currents are expected to reverse some time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the electrons are alternating between 2 hot wires which has a voltage of 240V. Imaging those two hot wires like left and right jabs from a boxer, and  the neutral wire is neither the left or the right jab, but a third arm in the middle not jabbing at all....So the electrons come from left arm, then come from the right arm like alternating jabs, and all return through the middle arm. The voltage between the middle arm and the left or right arm is 120V. Since there is no electron coming from the middle arm (no jab), you won't get a electric shock, or punched:)

Comment: You're describing a [Split-phase electric power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-phase_electric_power) system, but that's not what the OP is asking about. This question is about a simple [Single-phase electric power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-phase_electric_power) setup.

Answer (score 0):

In a120 volt circuit the neutral wire carries current at 120 volts every other 1/2 cycle, however the voltage potential voltage potential between the neutral and ground is 0 because the neutral is connected to ground,ie there is no voltage potential difference.